# How to get chart value statistics properly

Tags: mysql, charts, group-by

I need to get the sum of sales everyday...grouped by day....and grouped by item.
I have tried all sorts of queries, but am not sure if I need to be doing a join or what not.

So heres my table

```
Item | Price | Day
Apple    2      May1
Banana   3      May1
Apple    2      May1
Banana   3      May2
Apple    2      May2
Banana   3      May2
```

I need this returned for my charts...

{period: 'May1', 'apple': '4', 'banana': '3'},
{period:'May2', 'apple':'2', 'banana':'6'}

If someone can guide me in the correct direction that would be awesome.

Right now the furthest Ive gotten is grouped by day.....but I can't seem to group by day, and seperate by item.

Do I have to run seperate queries for each item?? and if so...how do I join it all together in the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT CONCAT('{\'period\':\'', day, '\',', GROUP_CONCAT(itemprice ORDER BY itemprice), '}') row
  FROM (SELECT day, CONCAT('\'', item, '\':\'', SUM(price), '\'') itemprice
          FROM table1
         GROUP BY day, item) n
GROUP BY day
```

Output:

```
|                                              ROW |
----------------------------------------------------
| {'period':'2013-05-01','Apple':'4','Banana':'3'} |
| {'period':'2013-05-02','Apple':'2','Banana':'6'} |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a85ae/16)**

UPDATE: To get all items for every day

```
SELECT CONCAT('{\'period\':\'', day, '\',', GROUP_CONCAT(itemprice ORDER BY itemprice), '}') row
  FROM (
SELECT day, CONCAT('\'', item, '\':\'', SUM(price), '\'') itemprice
  FROM (
SELECT a.day, a.item, IFNULL(t.price, 0) price
  FROM (SELECT day, item FROM
        (
         (SELECT DISTINCT item FROM table1) i CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT DISTINCT day FROm table1) d
        )) a LEFT JOIN
       table1 t ON a.day = t.day AND a.item = t.item    
       ) m
 GROUP BY day, item) n
GROUP BY day
```

Output:

```
|                                              ROW |
----------------------------------------------------
| {'period':'2013-05-01','Apple':'4','Banana':'3'} |
| {'period':'2013-05-02','Apple':'2','Banana':'6'} |
| {'period':'2013-05-03','Apple':'2','Banana':'0'} |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05366/15)**

Comment: Thanks, that works, but how do I get it to output empty values for things that don't exist on certain days, but do on others.....for instance say May 1st I have bananas, but on May 3rd I sell no bananas, I still want my Javascript string to say 'Banana':'0' for that day

Comment: Well it looks like my charting software doesn't mind not having a key value for those values....so nevermind :)

Comment: @KyleKoopman You're certainly welcome. Glad it helped. See updated answer for getting all items for every day, but it's obviously slower then original version.